# Making a bash script that reconnect to AP when connection lost

Tags: wireless, networking, bash

I'm facing problems with WIFI on ubuntu
i tried to update the system but still the same
what happens is that i suddenly lose the connection with my router 
and when i press on the WIFI bar the system won't detect any APs
i have to uncheck "enable WIFI" option ,then re check it so it work,it automatically reconnect.

I'm thinking of making a bash script that detects when the pc is disconnected from the router for any reason, and when it is disconnected it disable then enable the wifi.
i mean like automating resetting the connection that possible ?

i guess i must use this

```
nmcli nm wifi off
nmcli nm wifi on
```

but how can i make the script know if the PC is disconnected from the WIFI ?

Comment: I have the same problem... see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1242798

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is more simple than you think:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ "$(ping -c 1 google.com)" ]; then
    nmcli nm wifi off
    nmcli nm wifi on
fi
```

Then you can use a cron job for this script to run at every minute.

Comment: Sidenote: This would reconnect if Google.com is down ;)

Comment: Have you seen google.com ever time in your life down?

Comment: Does it matter for the answer or not?

Answer (score 5):

Although the answer is correct, you have to take into account that:

1) it will work if the user is logged in or not --- this could be desired behavior or not, depending on the application;

2) if the reconnection delays more than 1 minute, you'll never get there...

I wrote a simple script that I can run with the starting scripts of my graphical session and that can be a good candidate. I redirect it's output to a file so that I can follow it my utility SLogger.

Here is the script --- you never know.

```
#!/bin/bash
while /bin/true; do
    if ! [ "$(ping -c 1 google.com)" ]; then
        echo "Warning: connection lost at $(date) -- restart"  
        nmcli nm wifi off
        sleep 5
        nmcli nm wifi on
        sleep 60
        if ! [ "$(ping -c 1 google.com)" ]; then
             echo "Waiting for connection going up at $(date)"
             sleep 60
        else 
             echo "Connection on at $(date)" 
        fi
#    else
#        echo "Connection OK on $(date)"
    fi
sleep 60
done
```